# MySQL: delete parent records with no children

Tags: mysql

How do I write a query that deletes records from a parent table for which no children exist?

I have a table `resume` and a table `personal_skill` that has a `resume_id` field to refer the resume table. I need to delete all the records in the resume table for which there is no `personal_skill` record with such resume_id.

I tried to do it like this:

```
    DELETE
    FROM
      resume
    WHERE
      version = 0
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                      FROM
                        personal_skill x
                      WHERE
                        x.resume_id = id)
```

but this query fails cause I can't use the table I'm deleting from in SELECT part.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your try plainly works here:

```
 DELETE 
 FROM resume     
 WHERE version = 0
   AND NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT id                       
     FROM personal_skill x
     WHERE x.resume_id = resume.id
  );
```

If it doesn't, perhaps the plain `id` was the problem (does personal_skill have an `personal_skill.id` column?).

An alternative is:

```
 DELETE resume  
 FROM resume 
 LEFT JOIN personal_skill 
    ON personal_skill.resume_id=resume.id 
 WHERE personal_skill.id IS NULL; -- or any non-NULLable column from personal_skill
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
DELETE FROM  resume
WHERE version = 0
AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM personal_skill x WHERE x.resume_id = id)=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DELETE resume FROM
resume LEFT OUTER JOIN personal_skill
ON resume.resume_id = personal_skill.resume_id
WHERE personal_skill.resume_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Try LEFT JOIN syntax:

```
DELETE R 
FROM resume R
LEFT JOIN personal_skill PS ON PS.resume_id = R.id
WHERE PS.id IS NULL AND R.version = 0
```